# How to keep the application window on top?

Tags: windows, windows-phone

I am trying to develop an app like application locker for windows phone. Whenever other applications are launched, I want my application window to be on the top of that selected application to lock that. How can I make my application window to be on the top of all windows ? Is there any windows API for doing it ?

Comment: Ah, the old game of [walls and ladders](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/17/10257351.aspx). You're approaching this problem entirely the wrong way. According to the reviews of comparable apps in the Microsoft store, this is not possible to implement properly.

Comment: And what would happen if another app was able to do the same thing? (Quick answer: [thus you cannot](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/03/10/10138969.aspx).)

Comment: The application window is not going to be always on the top. If the user gives the password correctly, It will let them to use their desired app. Or if they press home, It will go away. I just want my application window to be on top only when some applications are launched.